# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method BlurFilter. in flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I am trying to apply filter to BitmapData, but one error is 
    ***1180: Call to a possibly undefined method BlurFilter.***

this is my code:-

```
bmpData.applyFilter(bmpData,cropRect,new Point(),new BlurFilter( 10, 10, 1 ));
```

i am using flash.filters any one help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have forgotten to import the package into your project:

```
import flash.filters.BlurFilter;
```

Check it again, please.